# Sidebars don't appear

Tags: theming, 10

I am trying to add two sidebar regions, `sidebar_first` and `sidebar_second`, one region on top the other region.
Both regions should share the CSS styling from `sidebar` region but my problem is that both new sidebar regions don't appear at all, even though each one of them contain blocks.
`sidebar` doesn't contain any block.
What have I done wrong?

---

**subtheme.info.yml**

```
regions:
  sidebar_first: 'Sidebar First'
  sidebar_second: 'Sidebar Second'
  sidebar: 'Sidebar'
```

**templates/layout/page.html.twig** includes the following code

```
<div class="sidebar-grid grid-full">
  <main role="main" class="site-main">
    {{ page.content_above }}
    {{ page.content }}
  </main>
  {{ page.sidebar_first }}
  {{ page.sidebar_second }}
  {{ page.sidebar }}
</div>
```

**templates/layout/region--sidebar_first.html.twig**

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'region',
    'region--sidebar',
    'region--' ~ region|clean_class,
  ]
%}

{{ attach_library('MY_SUBTHEME_NAME/sidebar') }}

{% if content %}
  <aside{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    {{ content }}
  </aside>
{% endif %}
```

**templates/layout/region--sidebar_second.html.twig**

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'region',
    'region--sidebar',
    'region--' ~ region|clean_class,
  ]
%}

{{ attach_library('MY_SUBTHEME_NAME/sidebar') }}

{% if content %}
  <aside{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    {{ content }}
  </aside>
{% endif %}
```

Flushing all Drupal cache and all browser cache.

Comment: It must be `regions:`, not `regions`, in the .info.yml file.

Comment: I have fixed that typo and flushed all caches both in Drupal and in web browser but no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do these actions to get the new sidebar regions to appear:

### First action

I had to add a **placeholder block** empty of any content to the `sidebar` region, for that region to be parsed and used as a base to parse the other two new sidebar regions.

### Second action

I had to do some CSS with classes Drupal creates.
Drupal has created the following two classes and I had to work with them:

```
.region--sidebar-first
.region--sidebar-second
```

Note that these have h hyphen (`-`) after sidebar instead of an underscore (`_`) as I have originally used.